# Make DatePicker appear when switching between views

Tags: gwt, datepicker, datebox

I have multiple views, and in one of these views i have a DateBox. What i want to do is when i switch to dateBoxView, the DatePicker in DateBox must appear like a popup.
I tried this :

```
@UiField DateBox dateBox
...
dateBox.getDatePicker().setVisible(true)
```

But no result.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

[dateBox.showDatePicker()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html#showDatePicker%28%29);  ??  befre that [setvalue()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html#setValue%28java.util.Date%29)

Comment: oops ..you didn't mention it before.  :).Even though you can write your logic in presenters onreveal() right ??

Comment: Can i just do it from the owner class after the initWidget()?

Comment: you mean in constructor of view right??right after after initwidget??yup.

Comment: seems like slowly revealing your secrets :)

Comment: Oh Man! it's not working! i put it right after initWidget(), tried to put some focus on it! but no result

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it just after calling `initWidget` like.

```
initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
dateBox.getDatePicker().setVisible(true);
```

As you did it then it should work. The problem with switching multiple views only. check there. it might not clear root layout properly or not height define or may be other overlapping layout problem.

The problem may with this date picker layout view not added properly while switching view.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call showDatePicker() method after UI has rendered. Otherwise you will not get the Date picker at the right position. The below code snippet does that -

```
initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
dateBox.showDatePicker();
```